# Openstack authentication always get 401 HTTP response

Tags: amazon-web-services, authentication, curl, cloud, openstack

I am recently doing projects on openstack. I start it. I want to access openstack account through `RESTful API`. I read the API guide in the official website. The link is here http://developer.openstack.org/api-guide/quick-start/api-quick-start.html#authenticate.

I do the same way to do the authentication.

Here is my command:

```
curl -s -X POST https://url:5000/v2.0/tokens -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"auth": {"tenantName": "MyTenantName", "passwordCredentials": {"username": "'"myAccountNme"'", "password": "mypassword"}}}'
```

But everytime I just get `401 (Unauthorized)` response said `The request you have made requires authentication`. The error message is [here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VF2XV.png)

What's wrong with my request? My username and password is correct, I can use it to access my account from dashboard.

Comment: do you have access to the openstack logs? those may have more precise details

Comment: Thank you~ I have solved this problem

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using https, I think you get the error message because you do not specify a certificate. Use the --cert or --cacert option of curl. Something like this:

```
curl --cacert <your_crt_file> -X POST https://url:5000/v2.0/tokens -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"auth": {"tenantName": "MyTenantName", "passwordCredentials": {"username": "'"myAccountNme"'", "password": "mypassword"}}}'
```